# Xcode instantly crashes when i build my code 2nd time

Tags: c++, xcode, crash, sigabrt

I'm coding in C++ in Xcode version 15.0.1 and dealing with memories. When I try to run my code it's fine for the first time, everything behaves as I expected. But when I try to run for the 2nd time, it crashes if I call `print_all` function in previous run. And it gives this error:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   Xcode [659]

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

And here is the `print_all` function:

```cpp
void print_all(airline *head){
    airline *temp=head;
    while(temp){
        cout<<"\n###################################"<<endl;
        cout<<"### AIRLINE ID: " << temp->ID <<" ###"<<endl;
        cout<<"NAME:"<<temp->name<<endl;
        cout<<"FLIGHTS: ";
        flight *Tempflights= temp->flights;
        while(Tempflights){
            cout<<"#["<<Tempflights->ID<<"|"<<Tempflights->from<<"->"<<Tempflights->to<<"|"<<Tempflights->hour<<":"<<Tempflights->min<<"|"<<Tempflights->price<<"TRY]#";
            Tempflights=Tempflights->next;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

This happens in a specific project and specific inputs I give for the first run.

I restarted my Mac and deleted the DerivedData file. I tried to open a new project and the same thing happened.

I logged in App Store Connect.

Comment: Is it Xcode or your program that crashes?

Comment: XCode crashes as i mentioned.

Comment: which version of xcode?

Comment: Perhaps this is the same issue then: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/735161 - If you are running a version 15 release candidate, I suggest downgrading. Oh, I see it still crashes in the released version.  Perhaps _"Turns out you have to login your account in the appstoreconnect.apple.com to renew and agree all new agreements, once you did, Xcode stop crashes."_ is what's needed.

Comment: It's version 15.0.1

Comment: This issue doesnt happen in my other projects but just that one particular one. Maybe the problem is my code itself. I logged in appstoreconnect but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

A buddy of mine experienced a very similar issue in Swift with Xcode. We had run some test and found out that as soon as there are 2 repeat-while loops running in one file of the project then Xcode crashes with the same error as here.

The first build runs pefectly fine but when we try to build the 2nd time it crashes. A workaround is to do a clean build every time, but that is not really a satisfying workflow at all.